# passing a structure for comparison

Tags: c, pointers, struct, comparison

```
struct sign_in
{
    char password[MAX_NAME_LEN+1];//The password for each player
    char name[MAX_NAME_LEN+1];//Name of the people who can sign in
}



//prototype
int compare_names(char*, char*, struct sign_in*);


int compare_names(char*pName,char*pPassCode,struct sign_in *var)
{
    int iComparison = 1;
    int flag = 1;
    int iComparison2 = 1;
    int i = 0;

    for (i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
        printf("%s \t %s ", var[0].name,pName );
        if(iComparison != 0)
        {
            iComparison = strcmp(pName,var[i].name);
            i++;
        }
        if(iComparison2 != 0)
        {
            iComparison2 = strcmp(pPassCode,var[i].password);
            i++;
        }

        printf("%d", iComparison);
        printf("%d", iComparison2);
    }
}
```

I have updated my code and attempted to take into account many of the aspects that you guys have recommended and the good news is that it runs now. The bad news is that it still attempts to print some random jargon that I don't understand, it's just a collection of symbols usually. The structure this function compares against has six members so that's the reason for parameters on the first for loop.

Comment: Could you post the definition of struct sign_in?

Comment: after `int iComparisson,flag = 1;`, `while(iComparisson == 1)` is undefined behavior, using the value of an object with automatic storage duration while it is indeterminate.

Comment: added the definition

Comment: Doesn't your compiler warn about `strcmp(*pName,*var[i].name);`? That's a constraint violation if the prototype for `strcmp()` is in scope.

Comment: Remove both `*` from the `strcmp()` call.    And ensure `#include <string.h>` occurs before trying to use `strcmp()`.     The `while` loops are pointless at best, and undefined behaviour at worst.

Comment: @JMBTaylor Get a real compiler. If `<string.h>` is `#include`ed, the compiler *has to give you a diagnostic message* for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you've presented is a cornucopia of sloppyness. When programming, that's not really OK.

- You forgot the closing curly braces for the `struct sign_in` definition and the `compare_names()` function definition
- You did not initialize `iComparisson` to any value. `flag` is initialized, but `iComparisson` is not. Also, it's misspelled!
- Don't use `printf()` with a user-input as the format string, there could be a `%` in there. At the very least do `printf("%s", pname)`. And you probably want a `\n` in there too.
- `strcmp()` might return `-1` to mean `pName` sorts before `var[i].name` (and differs from it of course), so `while(iComparisson == 1)` does not do what you want
- you need to know the length of the `var` array and stop that loop before you run off the end
- `strcmp()` takes strings, which are pointers. When you call `strcmp(*pName, ...)` you're dereferencing the pName "pointer to char" to just a "char". It's like getting the first character from the pName string, and then putting that character value where a pointer-to-character value is expected. Not good. The situation with `var[i].name` is a bit more complicated because name is an array, but get rid of the star, it's not needed for that either.
- The second `while ()` loop will loop forever if the `iPassCode` does not match, you probably want `if ()`
- In your problem description you omit the closing backtick after `*var[i].password` and the closing double-quote after "invalid type argument of unaray", and you obviously mangled the compiler error message as well. This makes it harder to understand what you wrote and what went wrong.
- The `iPassCode == var[i].password` actually looks fine. It seems rather likely that this isn't the code you had a problem with, due to all the other ridiculous problems in your sample ...

Comment: I think I made most of the changes you recommended and updated my code.

Comment: In your latest version, the extra `i++` in each `if()` block doesn't make sense, you should just remove them. But also, it looks like you will consider it a successful login if someone uses a username which exists and a password for some other user.